# Functional style of ReactJs breaks encapsulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't get it right. Here the thing: I made two widgets, a TabBar and a TabNavigator. The tabNav contains the state with the index **currentSelectedTab**. So when a TabBar receives a user click, it notify the parent (TabNav) to do something (with a callback), and precisely the parent inject new props saying: my dear tabbar, select this tab: currentSelectedTab
and at the same time, tabNav display the right content for the tab.

so far so good. BUT, now I want the application to be able to set the TabNav to a specific tab. As soon as I introduce that, as a props,  it breaks the encapsulation of currentSelectedTab in the tabnav. It must be defined outside, in the application. And this sucks.

In a OOP perspective, I would have a setCurrentTab in the widget TabNav, but in FP, especially in React, this is forbidden. The only entry door for a widget is the props. (Refs are evil, right ?).

This mean that when the TabBar receive a user click, it will call a callback in the TabNav, and the TabNav will also have to call an upper callback, defined in the application. then this callback will change the application state, and set currentSelectedTab, and so it will be passed through props to the TabNav.

the fact that currentSelectedTab must be defined outside TabNav is simply horrible. don't you think so ? It looks to me that It breaks component encapsulation. How to do that properly ? Flux ? Same thing: currentSelectedTab don't have to be defined in a global state.

Basically it seems that if everything is functional, you end-up with a giant state on the top that contains stuff that belong to some widgets. The encapsulation is deeply broken.

May be someone could explain to me what is wrong here ?

Comment: Some code would help visualize what you are syaing

Comment: What functionality does the `TabNavigator` provide that couldn't be handled cleanly in your `TabBar`? I'm having trouble imagining why you couldn't let the TabBar handle navigation and pass it a `defaultSelectedTab` prop. The fact that they both have Tab in their names seems to suggest they're pretty coupled already. Do you intend to reuse the TabBar for something else? What's the generic use case?

Comment: it is a common way to do things. In flex for instance. see [that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-8000.html#WS70ef25857c0d979e-5df5db17123beb1864c-8000). their ViewStack is my TabNav and their ButtonBar is my TabBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to deal with that.
the app responsibility is just to provide an initial value. So I named my props: **initialSelectedTabIndex**
The TabNavigator is the owner of the current index, not the app, and will use a callback on TabBar to do the right thing (update its internal state that contains something like **selectedTabIndex**).
In this way the encapsulation is not broken. The app don't have to use a callback to resend the new index, it will be the TabNav to do that.

when **componentWillReceiveProps** occur in TabNav, I do NOTHING. because I don't want to override the internal state with the props initialSelectedTabIndex, because it is no longer an initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Having public method for setting selected tab in imperative languages is not much different from having prop that is meant to do the same thing in react.

As soon as you feel a need to control some property outside of the component it naturally becomes part of its public contract. In react this is mostly and preferably props, in common OOP languages - public class methods/fields.

It is not necessary for react prop to directly represent its internal state though. Its totally OK to use props as initial values for the state. There is even a special hook [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) that is meant to allow you to mutate your encapsulated internal state when props are changing.

Hope this clarify things a bit.

Comment: I tried componentWillReceiveProps and I think the issue is there is no in-between solution. I can't say "I pass the current tab index in props", and in the same time say "I use a current tab index in the state". I had this kind of bug:
I pass 0 as starting index for the widget via props, then I click on the tab, I go in tab 2, then for some reason a re-render occur in the app, so the previous props "0" comes in, via "componentWillReceiveProps", and override the current state which is "1". So I left the current tab for no reason.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps accepts `nextProps` parameter. You can check if nextProps.selectedTabIndex have changed compared to the current one and only then update state. This exact equivalent of calling public method to change index imperatively. You do not call it every time with the same index even if there was no reason for it to be called. Instead you call it only when you know change occurred. With props its the same - component mutate its state only when it knows that necessary changes in its props (public "interface") has been made.

Comment: this does not work. nextProps.selectedTabIndex is deprecated in my case. because I didn't decided where is the owner of this. If it is the app, it works, and the widget just notify the app that it must be changed. As soon as you decide to manage this in the state, to encapsulate it, it does not work, the app is out of sync. You can't store this field in two places.